# Vba-excel - copying a range of cells in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a cell and select it and the 13 rows below it so I can copy the selection go to the next column and paste it transposed.

My query is:

```
If cell.Value Like "*OR-*" Then
    Cells(ActiveCell, cell.Offset(0, 13)).Select
    cell.Copy 
    cell.Offset(0, 1)
    cell.Clear
```

I have no problem with copy and paste but it is selection what I want that is throwing me off

Answer (score 1):

First, copy 13 rows below is `Cell.Offset(13,0)` and not `Cell.Offset(0, 13)` (which is 13 column to the right).

Second, you don't need to `Select` the `Range` to copy it, just use the code below:

```
If Cell.Value Like "*OR-*" Then
    Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(13)).Copy
    Cell.Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Cell.Clear
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This worked the first time and later when I had the same issue.